# Launching new browser window from a custom WebKit browser view

Tags: cocoa, webkit

My MacOsX has a Cocoa app with a special controller/window that employs WebKit for browsing. I just found out that the browsed content may have links that should open new browser windows. Although I set the following two declarations (see below) for my webView - nothing happens when I click those links with my specialized window. Clicking them from a regular browser would re-open a window:

```
[[_webView preferences] setJavaScriptEnabled:YES];
[[_webView preferences] setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically:YES];
```

Am I missing a callback implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make yourself the UI delegate:

```
[webView setUIDelegate:self];
```

And implement `webView:createWebViewWithRequest:`. This method needs to create and return the new `WebView` object and the window to display it. If you do not want to create the new view programmatically, you can use a NIB and load that instead.

Comment: I did that, and I do get a call to the webView:createWebViewWithRequest method. however, the "request" is always nil. where do I intercept the URL of the link the user clicked on?

Comment: Is the window being opened using javascript? If so, there might not be a request. If there isn't a request, create a web view/window without sending a load message.

Comment: Though this is an old question, I'd like to provide an answer for those who get here: All window.open calls result in a createWebViewWithRequest: with a null request, then later a location change on that WebView.